# Prevent Cookies from being edited

Tags: php, cookies

There are many ways users can edit the content of their cookies. On my website, I have a cookie called "user" that stores the username that the user is currently logged in with. However, I just noticed that this cookie can be edited to log in to any account. Is there any code or parameter I can add to the setcookie() function, that blocks users from doing editing a certain cookie?

Answer (score 6):

> Is there any code or parameter I can add to the setcookie() function,
>   that blocks users from doing editing a certain cookie?

No, there isn't. Cookies can always be edited by the client. You should encrypt them if you want to store sensitive information. Actually the best way is to never store sensitive information in a cookie such as the username. It is recommended to store this in a server side session. The server side session itself can be tracked with a cookie but the sensitive information containing the username stays on the server.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that cookies shouldn't be used for this type of storage. The correct solution is server-side sessions in the overwhelming majority of cases.

Answer (score 3):

No, ultimately the cookie is stored on the client's machine and the client has access to it.  I would suggest storing a hash instead of the user's account name.  Take the hash from the cookie and retrieve the username from your data storage, if the hash has been manipulated then you won't get a proper username and you know you need them to log in again and create a valid hash in the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

No. A cookie is stored on the users computer, usually in a text file or something similar. It's best to not store user information in cookies, but keep that information in sessions. Sessions are stored on the server, so the user cannot edit them.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. A cookie is basically a text file on the clients computer and there is always some way to edit it.

But there is a simple solution to your problem: Save more information in cookies. For example you can store a hash code (like `md5()` or `sha1()`) of the password in a second cookie and then check if that hash corresponds to the user that the client "pretends" to be

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent a client to modify a cookie (It is saved on his machine after all).

What you can do is to validate the cookie on your side, to make sure it's legit and intact.

What I like to do is to send 2 cookies.

1. The username, not encrypted.
2. The username + password + random salt all encrypted.

This way you can validate your user and not have to worry about people changing it (because they need to know the password + the random salt + the hashing function).

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is issue a cookie that is essentially a token.  Here is what I have done in the past

```
function get_token(){
    $token = md5(date("l").$_SERVER['USER_AGENT'].date("d"));
    return $token;
}

$token = get_token();
setcookie($token);
```

Then when you want to check it:

```
$token = get_token();
if($token == $_COOKIE['token']){
    echo 'show the good page here';
} else {
    echo 'user is not authenticated.. display login page';
}
```

As long as the client is passing the user agent, the token will be accepted until the day changes.

Answer (score 0):

For sticky session (session affinity) load balanced systems or monolithic non distributed systems or in a full scalable system using a shared caching mechanism (like redis), in your login page, you can create a session cookie which is non persistent and is stored in the memory of the browser which you can use it to store whatever "protected" data you want to store. Using the following code you set some headers needed to protect this cookie. The httponly headed which will block javascript to access the cookie, the secure header which prohibits cookie data to be transferred via non encrypted channels, and the use only cookies to prevent attacks involved passing session ids in URLs.

```
ini_set('session.cookie_secure','1');
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly','1');
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies','1');

session_start();
```

depending on the version of php and the browser you can also use the samesite header with Lax depending on whether you want cross domain requests or not. All header setters should be before session creation (`session_start();`).

```
ini_set('session.cookie_samesite','Lax');
```

Then, when your user gets authenticated you can store the value of the username inside the session cookie.

```
$_SESSION['username']=$_POST['username']
```

This way no-one will be able to change its value. Keep in mind though, that cookies are prone to CSRF attacks and you will need in each POST request a sync token which will validate that the request is coming from an authenticated user.

For distributed systems without any shared caching you can use the JWT (JSON Web Tokens) which have their contents signed using a hashed message authentication code (HMAC) cryptographic algorithm and a secret (private key) that is distributed to all the systems in need of reading or signing the contents. Thus if you change the username stored, the token fails validation because the digest of the contents is changed.